# <s-f10> cannot be mapped in neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

At least not on my mac. it works fine in vim. is this simply an error in nvim?

Comment: When you insert a literal `<S-F10>` (`<C-v><S-F10>` in insert mode), what is displayed? On my system, with Vim, I see: `^[[21;2~`. I can't use `<S-F10>` by default, because Vim doesn't recognize the previous sequence of keycodes, so I have to teach that it means `<S-F10>`. To do this, I have to write in my `vimrc`: `silent! exe "set <S-F10>=\e[21;2~"` The keycodes to the right of the equal sign are the same as the ones displayed when inserting a literal `<S-F10>`. Except for the leading `^[` which must be replaced by `\e` (escape keycode). After that I can use `<S-F10>`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @user9433424, thank you! that solved it. in nvim, shifting turns f1 to f13, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem of mapping Shift+Fx keys combination on different systems. Unfortunately solutions were also different.

I wanted to map `Shift+F8`. On one system I had to put the following into my vimrc:

```
set<s-F8>=^[[32~
nnoremap <S-F8> :cprev<CR>
```

The combination of characters "^[[32~" in the first line was created by pressing `Ctrl-v` and then `Shift-F8` keys in insert mode.

With neovim this approach did not work. Pressing `Ctrl-v` and then `Shift-F8` in insert mode resulted in following characters: "".

But the following mapping command works just fine:

```
nnoremap <F20> :cprev<CR>
```

Strange, but it actually maps `Shift+F8` key combination.